# How to add vuetify to default vuepress theme

Tags: vuetify.js, vuepress

Is it possible to add vuetify to default vuepress theme ?

I just need to add few components to default theme however it would be nice to use the vuetify for handling forms within my components.

I have found a custom vuepress theme which uses a vuetify, however I would prefer to use default vuepress theme.

Another option is to eject the default theme and add the vuetify to it. However I would prefer not to eject the default theme just add vuetify to it.

Answer (score 8):

The [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53199908/10577234) from [oscarteg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3714327/oscarteg) got me most of the way there. Here's what I had to do for the `.vuepress/enhanceApp.js` file (and yes, if you do not have one go ahead and create it).

```
import Vuetify from "vuetify";
import "vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css";
export default ({
  Vue, // the version of Vue being used in the VuePress app
  options, // the options for the root Vue instance
  router, // the router instance for the app
  siteData // site metadata
}) => {
  Vue.use(Vuetify);
  options.vuetify = new Vuetify({})
};
```

Note that in the `new Vuetify({})` passed to `options.vuetify` you can set your theming.

See https://github.com/vuejs/vuepress/issues/681#issuecomment-515704018

Comment: This is so helpful - and should be the accepted answer!!

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way would be to use the vuetify CDN. In your `config.js` add something like

```
module.exports = {
  head: [
          ['link', { rel: 'stylesheet', href: `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css` }],


    ['script', { src: `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js` }],
    ['script', { src: `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js` }],
  ]
}
```

Something like that. See https://vuepress.vuejs.org/config/#head

Another way would be to install the vuetify package and add `Vuetify` to  `enhanceApp`. It would look like this in your `.vuepress/enhanceApp.js`

```
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'

export default ({
  Vue, // the version of Vue being used in the VuePress app
  options, // the options for the root Vue instance
  router, // the router instance for the app
  siteData // site metadata
}) => {
    Vue.use(Vuetify)
}
```

See https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/basic-config.html#theme-configuration

Comment: This gets you most of the way there but see the answer from @mike wright for the rest of it!